# How to query data rows with id is specified by another query with Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID IN (SELECT user_id FROM some_table WHERE something)
```

Can anyone provide me the solution for how to do this using `Django queryset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 nested querysets, something like:

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=SomeModel.objects.filter(field=something).values_list('user_id', flat=True))
```

Hope it helps!